# filemaker 16 curl call

Tags: php, curl, filemaker

I hav a php script that executes a curl call with filemaker data (the script draws data from my db via php calls).

Filemaker 16 supports curl calls directly.

I want to run the same call using filmmakers insert from url script step.

I managed to build up a call but it is failing, at the beginning with an error (there was no data transferred to the server) and now, without any notifications.

My working PHP script:

```
    $headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8',
    'Expect: ',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body)
    );
    $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    $res=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($res);
```

My curl options on filemaker

```
"--header \"Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8\" --header \"Expect: \" --header \"Content-Length: "&Length ( $vevent )&"\" --user-agent \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)\" --basic  --user "&$password&" --request \"PUT\" --data \"@$vevent\""
```

Has anybody got experience in formulating curl options in filmmaker 16?

My script call in filmmaker 16 does not work, I do not get an error, but the data is not successfully uploaded to the server (it is ical data, correctly formulated, the same data works in php)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry, my question is, how do I pass the data to the server. This works in my original PHP script, but not with filemaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't pass the $vevent variable correctly.
Try this:

```
--data \"" & $vevent & "\""
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this error now:  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><error xmlns='DAV:'><valid-calendar-data xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'/></error>.    Even if I "GET" a valid, already existing calendar entry, and try to "PUT" it, I still get this error (there was some progress with your suggestion though!)

Comment: I suggest you flag the question as answered and start another one. And try POST instead of PUT